# How do I change data during serialization with JSON.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, datatables, json.net

I'm using [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/documentation) 4.5r7 in an MVC4 non-api project.

Below I rename "id" to DT_RowId for DataTables "mDataProp", but also want to change the data, e.g. [42 becomes "row_42"](http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/php/browsers.php) during serialization.

```
sealed public class Species
{
    [JsonProperty("DT_RowId")]
    public long id { get; private set; } // Change me to row_{n}

    public int amu { get; private set; }

    public string chemicalFormula { get; private set; }
...
}
```

The documentation is a little hard to follow for someone not familiar with the library, and examples are lacking.

I can add a "row_n" property to each class, but coupling the view with the model is evil™

The question is: How to I alter the serialized data with JSON.net to achieve this result?

Comment: Of some note is I am using an MVC controller "ActionResult" substitute similar to: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the action instead of returning the model you could easily create an anonymous object using linq query and return it.

```
public JsonNetResult TestAction()
{
     ...

     var query = species.Select(s => new // species is a collection
     {  
        DT_RowId = .. you can change data as you need from s.id,
        amu = s.amu,
        chemicalFormula = s.chemicalFormula 
        ...
     });

     return new JsonNetResult{ Data = query.ToList() };

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would indeed work, though would  couple the controller to the implementation details of the model, which is like what I was trying to avoid. Perhaps I can use reflection to add properties of any model class, though that sounds like it could be a bumpy road (what to exclude, etc.)